# Laravel при переназначении имени сломал приложение

Tags: php, laravel

Суть в том, что нужно было изменить имя приложения 
использовал команду php artisan app:name "DKP Online" - да, косякнул, случайно вставил пробел, теперь имею целый ряд ошибок начиная от :

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'Online' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in /home/andreii/dkp_stat/bootstrap/app.php on line 31
```

После того как избавился от нее - вылез еще больший набор :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class 

DKPOnline\Http\Kernel does not exist in /home/andreii/dkp_stat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:794
Stack trace:

#0 /home/andreii/dkp_stat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(794): ReflectionClass->__construct('DKPOnline\\Http\\...')
#1 /home/andreii/dkp_stat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(671): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('DKPOnline\\Http\\...')
#2 /home/andreii/dkp_stat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(265): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('DKPOnline\\Http\\...', Array, false)
#3 /home/andreii/dkp_stat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(791): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#4 /home/andreii/dkp_stat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(671): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#5  in /home/andreii/dkp_stat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 794
```

Собственно все файлы перерыл.. Ничего не могу найти.

Как можно откатить ? (на гите коммиты слишком старые)

Comment: так надо было иметь бекап до изменений, зачем вам гит если вы не можете откатиться к определенной точке? тем более такой важной... ¯|_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: попробуйте вручную сменить конфиг config/app.php `'name' => 'name'` и .env `APP_NAME=name`, после - `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Данные действия не помогли.

Comment: естественно) написал, потом подумал.. там неймыспейсы тоже меняются.. можно вручную искать неймспейсы и менять их, можно попробовать

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.

В VSCode - нашел все значения с "новым именем" и заменил его.

После этого выполнил

```
composer update 
php artisan config:clear
```

И все завелось...